# Can you use more then one css tag for the body content in a website?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to be able to edit 3 different body css tags.  I want one page to not include any overflow scrollbars but I need another page to use a vertical scroll only and the third to use a horizontal scroll only.

is it possible to do this? I read somewhere it can cause some browsers to choke but Im not sure how reliable that source was.

Also how would you call it in the CSS if it was a Class would it be written like any other CSS?

```
    .body1{
    }

    .body2{

    }
    .body3{
}
```

Comment: One page with 3 bodies? No, use a div for each one...

Comment: Same script/file delivering three different pages based on parameters or one script/file delivering a single page with three different areas.  The solution will be different for each case.

Comment: he isn't asking for multiple body tags within the same page, he is asking for different body tag styles across a site.

Comment: CSS doesn't have tags, and that's the primary confusion here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are actually asking **"How can I style the `body` tag differently on each page of a website".**

Similar to your original suggestion, I would add an `id` instead of a `class` to the `body` tag:

**Page 1 HTML**

```
<body id="firstPage">
```

**Page 2 HTML**

```
<body id="secondPage">
```

**Page 3 HTML**

```
<body id="thirdPage">
```

Then in the **CSS** you would target them like this:

```
#firstPage{
    /*styling in here*/
}

#secondPage{
    /*styling in here*/
}

#thirdPage{
    /*styling in here*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question's title is that:

## No, you can't use many body tags inside an HTML document.

However, to have many scrollbars, use CSS:

```
.scrollableContainer
{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

You can simply have thee different `div` elements on your page.

Comment: I don't think that's the question he is asking, but you're right.

Comment: I agree.  I think the better option would be to update (edit) the question title to reflect the question detail. I have now done this (waiting for approval).

Answer (score 1):

Honestly you can have [multiple](http://jsbin.com/uzavov/edit#javascript,html,live) `body` tags or even [nested bodies](http://jsbin.com/okakaj) in your website. Most of browsers will render your page as you expected. But it's not *valid* HTML to have multiple body tags in one page. If you want different overflows in your different pages and you only have one css file to do this you can add class or id to your body tag to target every specific page body tag in your CSS file. To add id to your body tag you can use server side scripts or JavaScript.

To add an ID to your page using JavaScript add this script tag in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
document.body.setAttribute("id", "thePage1Id");
</script>
```

Then in your CSS file you can use those ID's to target your pages:

```
body#thePage1Id{overflow:auto;}
body#thePage2Id{overflow:scroll}
...
```

In reply to [duri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605142/duri):

I had to reply you here becasue I need to sho you this image:

[image]

Just because webkit browsers ignore multiple body tag you can't say we can't have multiple bodies. Still you can have multiple bodies in a page but it's not valid HTML and maybe it don't work well.

Comment: Have you tried looking what `document.getElementsByTagName('body').length` returns? I'm sure it'll be always `1`. In HTML, you **cannot** have multiple bodies; your answer is misleading. Use Firebug or similar developer tools to see what is the actual DOM tree.

Comment: You've displayed the original source. Try pressing F12 to open IE Developer Tools.

Comment: I agree that it will not render multiple bodies

Answer (score 0):

No you cannont use more than 1 body tag in a page but you can apply a different style to the body tag on different pages as you suggest - yes of course.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a different stylesheet to control the body tag for each page layout.

So: 
page one pulls in page1.css (with accompanying body styles - no overflow scrollbars)
page two pulls in page2.css (with accompanying body styles - vertical scroll only)
page three pulls in page3.css (with accompanying body styles - horizontal scroll only)

(obviously without stupid file names)

I like this better than multiple style sets within a single file for readability and maintainability.

Comment: I have to disagree with you. Either you are suggesting: 1) replicating all of the styles 2 more times in separate style sheets or 2) you would only have the other `body` styles in separate style sheets. In the first case this is definitely not more maintainable as you would have to change three style sheets every time you changed something. In the second case it would be a waste of another http request for the second style sheet, and again a pain to have to open up another file just to edit the one style.

Comment: I don't think the body tags are likely to be the only elements that would exist in these page specific sheets. It sounds like the pages are for completely different purposes and would have a whole batch of styles that are specific to them. But, yes, that's a big assumption. If the assumption holds, however, it is more efficient as the stylesheets will be smaller, more than making up for the overhead associated with the extra request.